# How to get ID of tag with html generated with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have something like this:

```
td = '<td id = "someId"> Text <input type = "text" name = "someName" value = "someValue" onchange="textChange(' + "someId" + ')"></td>';

var tag = document.createElement("tr");
tag.innerHTML = td;
document.getElementById("mainTable").appendChild(tag);
```

But the part:

```
"textChange(' + "someId" + ')"
```

is wrong because if i want to reference like this:

```
document.getElementById("someId").name
```

This is undefined.

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `td` 'someId' don't have the property name.
It's from your `input text`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I thought it was because this is dynamically generated html by javascript and is invisible on 'Ctrl U'.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to give you actual code, since you didn't give us actual code, but you are probably looking for something like `onchange="textChange(this.parentNode.getAttribute('id'))"`

That being said, this is not the best way to handle DOM manipulation.  Have you considered looking into a JavaScript framework such as [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)?  These frameworks make tedious tasks like this very simple.  The jQuery syntax would be something like `$(this).parent().attr('id')`